# How to handle concerns shared by module namespaced controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport-concern

I have a controller that looks something like this:

```
module Guardians
  class StudentsController < ApplicationController   

    def show
      @student = Student.find params[:id]

      authorize @student, policy_class: StudentPolicy
    end
  end
end
```

Because the controller is within a module, the policy class which is used is `Guardians::StudentPolicy`, which is what I want.

However I now have another controller:

```
module Teachers
  class StudentsController < ApplicationController   

    def show
      @student = Student.find params[:id]

      authorize @student, policy_class: StudentPolicy
    end
  end
end
```

Here the policy_class used is `Teachers::StudentPolicy`

But because the show method itself is identical, ideally I would like to dry this up with a concern. However if I cannot seem to do this, as

`authorize @student, policy_class: StudentPolicy`

will no longer automatically call the namespaced policy class when it is called from inside the concern.

What is the DRYest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a concern like this:

```rb
module StudentsConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    before_action :find_and_authorize_student, only:[:show]
  end

  private

  def find_student_and_authorize
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    if self.class.name.deconstantize == 'Teachers'
      authorize @student, policy_class: Teachers::StudentPolicy
    else
      authorize @student, policy_class: Guardians::StudentPolicy
    end
  end
end
```

And then include this in both of the controllers and clear the show actions.